# Is it is ok to Write controllerJs and Html part in application Bundle resource rather than component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, lightning-apps

My question is more towards design approach than being code specific.

I have a requirement in lightning migration where I need to convert their existing Vf page that comes as inline Vf in account detail compatible with lightning experience as well as salesforce 1 mobile app (android/ios and all devices).
So basically the Vf displays list of related custom object records, with each record having edit and delete link associated with it. onclick of edit(link) or add button(shown at bottom of saved records table), renders a section that enables the user to add or edit related record.
I have developed a component where I can pass in List of sobject records and list of columns and it renders as expected. Now to initialize values to be passed I can either do it in seperate component can store it in its local aura attribute and can then pass in to its child display records component.

```
<c:DisplayAccountRecords>
     <aura:attribute name="recordList" type="CustomObj__c[]" />
     <aura:attribute name="columnList" type="String[]" />
     <c:DisplayRecords recordList="{!v.recordList}" columnList="{!columnList}" />
</c:DisplayAccountRecords>
```

Or I can directly wrap it in `aura:application` that does the same logic in its controller.

Also, I want the DisplayRecord component to be shown with the horizontal scrollbar as the number of fields are high. For that also I can write custom Ui either in the parent DisplayAccountRecords component or lightning out aura application.
Is `aura:application` Ui, controller,helper,renderer resources are meant to serve these specific use cases only, As basically code writting in aura:application are not reusable.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

In Object Oriented programming languages, the best solution is often to add more classes rather than to add more complexity to the existing classes. And in my experience the same is true for Lightning Components: more components leads to a cleaner design.

Somewhat more formally, it is the [Single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) that is in play. In this case, the `aura:application`'s job would be to adapt your root `aura:component` to work in a Visualforce page and nothing else. The extra logic you detail would be placed in an extra layer or layers of `aura:component`s.

With this approach, if you wanted to re-use this work via the [Lightning App Builder](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/lightning_app_builder) in the future that hosts `aura:component`s directly, less change would be involved as the logic would already be in a root `aura:component`.

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_aura_application.htm):

> **aura:application**
> An app is a special top-level component whose markup
>   is in a .app resource.
> The markup looks similar to HTML and can
>   contain components as well as a set of supported HTML tags. The .app
>   resource is a standalone entry point for the app and enables you to
>   define the overall application layout, style sheets, and global
>   JavaScript includes. It starts with the top-level 
>   tag, which contains optional system attributes. These system
>   attributes tell the framework how to configure the app.

implies that you *could* put your logic in there but by my reading does not particularly encourage that you *do*.